# Porqué no puedo desplegar la carpeta assets en Android Studio?

Tags: android

me está pasando una cosa bastante extraña. Estoy haciendo un juego utilizando android studio y libgdx. Al principio estaba usando dos modulos, el "android" y el "core", pero decidí pasar a utilizar solo el de android y moví todas las clases a dicho modulo. El caso es que no puedo desplegar la carpeta "assets". Los recursos están ahí (si pulso "ver en el explorador" los puedo ver) y siguen funcionando,
pero es muy incomodo no poder acceder directamente. ¡Muchas gracias! [image]

Como se puede apreciar ni me aparece la flecha para poder abrir la carpeta...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Click derecho sobre la carpeta y pulsa en la opción `Reload form Disk` o similar. O cierra y vuelve a abrir Android Studio.

Comment: Ya probé las dos cosas y nada. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un captura de pantalla de lo que sale cuando le das a `Ver en el explorador`?